# Using Add XY Tool

Tags: shapefile, features, xyz

I am trying to add the Lat / Long to my attribute table for a number of points.

The issue I am encountering is that the layer I wish to work with is not appearing in the drop down menu when using the Add XY data Tool.

I received this data from a third party, and it is sensitive information, though as a First Nations we have rights to it, so is it possible that they somehow blocked this action?

Comment: Can be multipoint.

Comment: Is it possible to add XY to multipoint?

Comment: Actually you are right, I assumed they were points, but for some reason they have them as polygons.

Comment: Are you using ArcGIS Pro, ArcMap or something else?